# PHP fastest way to register millions of records in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have to register millions of page views in my DB, I'm looking for the best solution to decrease the server load.

**1. Actual solution: check if is unique and register in "raw" table and "optimized" table**

```
// script
$checkUnique = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT FROM rawTable
         WHERE datatime = '$today' AND ip = '$ip'
         ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1" );
mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO rawTable ( id, datetime, url, ip, ua )
         VALUES ( NULL, '$now', '$url', '$ip', '$ua' )" );
if( mysqli_num_rows( $checkUnique ) == 0 ) {
    mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO optimizedTable ( id, day, total )
                         VALUES ( NULL, '$today', 1 )" ); }
else{
    mysqli_query( $con, "UPDATE optimizedTable SET total = total + 1
            WHERE day = '$today' ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1"; }
```

**2. Register the views only in "raw" table, and then with cronjob populate the "optimized" table**

```
// script
mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO rawTable ( id, datetime, url, ip, ua, alreadyOptimized )
         VALUES ( NULL, '$now', '$url', '$ip', '$ua', 0 )" );

// cronjob -> check if is unique, populate mysql tables +
//         change column alreadyOptimized from 0 to 1 in raw table
```

**3. Register the raw views in a txt or csv file, and then populate the mysql tables with cronjob**

```
// script
$file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, "$now,$url,$ip,$ua\n");

// cronjob -> check if is unique, populate mysql tables + delete rows from txt/csv file
```

What is the best (lightest and fastest) way? Are there any better solutions?

*PS: The server load is caused by the select query to check if the views are  unique*

Comment: Great question. I think the #3rd option is better, but in this case I think is a question of flavours. If you let the task to a cronjob, you'll don't notice a bad performance because it runs late in night, for example

Comment: I agree with Marcos. Further tips: LOAD DATA INFILE is crazy fast (though not secure), it might help you to import the csv files in a short amount of time. I'd do actual processing/data analysis in a batch job, the cron way. Processing these crazy piles of data, you'll run into memory exhaust issues for sure. To omit that, you'll need to process in chunks of x records (repetitively start that process). You may need to create a cron/daemon like job that contiously fires that process up for you.  Thus spreading system memory/cpu usage over the day.

Comment: I don't think that text files are a good option, since multiple users would have to write into it. I would use either the 2nd approach or a different intermediate layer between the optimised table and the event, such as memory based database or a nosql solution. instead of separate insert and update I would use the insert ... on duplicate key update ... version.

Comment: All 3 options are awful. Never select to check if record exists, use `UNIQUE` constraint and use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: What's the traffic (number of updates/second) you want to handle?

Comment: As a side comment, do you have indexes on columns `datetime` and `ip`?

Comment: Have you considered using [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or [redis](http://redis.io) for storing your unique views?

Comment: Bug in #1?  The `SELECT` checks for date+ip; the `UPDATE` ignores ip.

Answer (score 10):

Manually selecting to check if record exists is the worst thing you can do - it can (and will) produce false results. There's a time lag between MySQL and any process connecting to it. The only proper way is to place `UNIQUE` constraint and simply just `INSERT`. That's the only way to be 100% certain your DB won't contain duplicates.

The reason this is interesting for your use case is that it cuts your code down by 50%. You don't have to `SELECT` first, therefore you get rid of a huge bottleneck.

Use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if you need to update the existing record.

Your unique constraint would be compound index on `datetime, ip` columns. To even further optimize this, you can create a `binary(20)` column in your table and have it contain a `sha1` hash of `datetime, ip` combination. Using triggers, you can create the hash before inserting, making the whole process invisible to actual person inserting into table.

If insert fails, record exist. If insert succeeds, you've done what you wanted to. No `SELECT` being used should yield performance. After that, if it's still slow - it's simply the limit of I/O of the server you use and you need to look for optimizations on hardware level.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - very useful comment, thanks for taking time to help improve my answer.

Comment: I just want to point out that if for some reason some day they decide to migrate to a database which does not support `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` this will have to be changed. So I guess a more generic solution might be impemented by using `redis` (or similar).

Comment: @mrun at the moment, OP is using MySQL and question is about MySQL specifically. Migrating to a different storage solution wasn't mentioned, and the question refers to how to solve the issue using MySQL. Please, do provide an answer using a different storage solution, by all means.

Comment: @Mjh I absolutely agree with you but I also think it never hurts to keep in mind what might change in the not so distant future.

Comment: @mrun - it's not related to the question, suggesting "potential" changes of storage engine is out of scope here, isn't it?

Comment: @N.B. Isn't this what comments are for? I haven't proposed an answer for something 'potential', right? All I wanted was to improve the answer by presenting an alternative point of view. And please accept my apologies if I have gotten off-topic here. I'll be glad to delete my comments if they're not useful.

Comment: @Mjh thanks, could you please write a sample code for my case with `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to better understand how it works?

Comment: Don't use a sha1 index unless you can be sure it is _completely_ cached.  Otherwise the _random_ nature of it will lead to a lot of I/O.

Comment: " Millions of records" -- per/what?  Per day -- no problem.  Per minute -- none of the solutions given will be fast enough.  Also, is this a million-row batch process?  Or a continual stream?  The optimal solutions differ drastically.

Comment: Another argument against sha1 -- it takes more space than date+ip.  Date seems to be `DATE` (3 bytes) and ip, even IPv6, could be `BINARY(16)`; total = 19.

Comment: @RickJames - your comments are really not constructive, are people supposed to google what it means "sha1 index completely cached" or "sha1 index random nature" to understand what you meant? Why don't you simply post your own answer? Also, as you can notice - the OP never specifies whether it's `DATE` or `DATETIME` in question, but query posted hints it's `DATETIME`. `8 + 16 > 20`, so the suggested technique to hash the result works. In the end, it's irrelevant because the answer covers how to avoid duplicates and the need to check for them.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers given so far are anywhere near close to "fastest".

A *single* IODKU ([INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)) replaces all of the steps given.  However, it is unclear what the `PRIMARY KEY` should be.  Some hint at a "date" + IP, some hint at a "datetime" + IP.  But what if the user uses two different browsers ($ua) from the same IP?  Or comes from a different page ($url)?

Chunk the data as a way to avoid system impact.  That is, do *not* process one row at a time.  And do *not* throw a million rows at the table all at once.  The former is sloooow -- typically ten times as slow as some form of batching.  The latter will have severe impact on the target table.

If you suddenly have a million-row batch of values to insert/increment, preprocess it.  That is, boil it down to counts per unique key *before* updating the real data.  This decreases the impact on the real table, though it possibly has some overall "system" impact.  But, furthermore, chunk the data -- say 1000 rows at a time -- to copy into the real table.  [More on Chunking](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).

If you have hundreds or thousands (but not millions) of 'rows' coming in every *second*, then there are a couple of options.  First, do they all come from a single source?  Or are they coming from multiple clients?

From a single source -- Gather a thousand rows, combine them, then build a single IODKU to do them all.  (Note how to use the `VALUES` pseudo-function.)

From multiple sources -- ping-pong a pair of tables.  Collect raw info in one table from all the clients.  Another thread processes the other table a la chunking for puts the data into the real table.  Then this thread flips the tables using a single, atomic, RENAME TABLE; the clients will be oblivious to it.  [More on high speed ingestion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).

Meanwhile, you should normalize at least the $ua, since they are bulky and highly repetitious.  That last link shows a 2-sql method for efficient bulk normalization.

Another note:  The target table should have the "unique" key for IODKU be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  If you currently have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, move it out of the way by turning it into `INDEX` instead of `PRIMARY KEY`.  (Yes, that does work.)  The rationale is to make the `UPDATE` part of IODKU faster by not going through a secondary key, and not having a second `UNIQUE` key to check.

Comment: `None of the answers given so far are anywhere near close to "fastest"` - there's 1 answer besides yours - mine. `A single IODKU (INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..) replaces all of the steps given` - exactly what I wrote. You'd probably know had you read a) the question and b) the answer.

Comment: @Mjh - If there are millions of rows being fed to a single IODKU, there is the extra cost of logging (for `ROLLBACK`) all the inserts and updates.  For thousands of rows, this is not a problem.  But for millions, InnoDB resorts to more I/O to handle the volume.  Hence the total time _may_ be slower than chunking 1K rows at a time.  Furthermore, if replication is involved, nasty things can happen when the slave suddenly gets the million-row IODKU.

Comment: @Mjh - It seems that `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Well, IODKU "burns" ids.  Overflowing, say, `INT`, would be a worse problem than deciding which is 'faster'.

Comment: Rick, there's `bigint`. I'm sure you can calculate what the max number is, along with the rate of "burning" it'd take to get even close to overflowing it.